# Need to Implement Custom Search in Select2 by using Asynchronous Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, blazor, jquery-select2, blazor-server-side

I am developing wrapper over **Select2** plugin to make a reusable **Blazor Component**. I have integrated it's basic usage in Blazor using the `JSInterop`.
Now, I am stuck in a problem while integrating custom search by using a custom function for the matcher.
Actually, everything works fine but I am not getting the results as I am bound to use `async function` for the matcher. I have to use

```
var result = await dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync(searchMethodName, params.term, filterItems);
```

to get the searched results from a `JSInvokable` search method.

The method is hitting correctly and returning the results properly. But, as the matcher function in the **Select2** is synchronous and my custom function is asynchronous, it doesn't show the results in the `SelectBox` because the interpreter doesn't wait for the `C#` method to return the result.

I am sharing my **Select2** `init` code below, so that anyone can help me to get a solution:

```
$(id).select2({
            placeholder: placeholder,
            allowClear: isClearAllowed,
            minimumResultsForSearch: minSearchResults,
            minimumInputLength: minimumInputLength,
            maximumInputLength: maximumInputLength,
            matcher: async function (params, data) {
                if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
                    return data;
                }
                if (typeof data.children !== 'undefined') {
                    //Grouped Item
                    var filterItems = [];
                    data.children.forEach(function (e) {
                        filterItems.push({ id: e.id, text: e.text, isDisabled: e.disabled, selected: e.selected });
                    });
                    var result = await dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync(searchCallback, params.term, filterItems);
                    if (result.length) {
                        var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
                        modifiedData.children = data.children.filter(function (x) {
                            return result.some((r) => r.id === x.id);
                        });
                        return modifiedData;
                    }
                }
                else if (typeof data.id !== 'undefined' && data.id != "") {
                    //UnGrouped Item
                }

                //No Item
                return null;
            }
        });
```

I am `C#` developer who knows little about the `JavaScript` that's why I might missing something here. Blazor also provides non-async function to invoke the `C#` method but that is only available in **WebAssembly**. I am making this plugin to be available for both **Blazor Server and WebAssembly**.

I will be grateful if someone help me over making an async call for a sync function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trying for several hours, I have found and implemented a solution which works well.

First, I created a custom `SelectAdapter` and made the required methods `async`. I had to implement some different logic to get the sequential results. I did a change in `Select.prototype.matches` function and added `await` keyword with the matcher function call. In `Select.prototype.query` function I also changed the way of calling the `self.matches(params, option)` function for each option. I took the help from [this blog post](https://bojanv91.github.io/posts/2017/10/extending-select2-with-adapters-and-decorators) and used the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/select2/select2) to find out the original functions.

```
$.fn.select2.amd.define("CustomSelectAdapter", ["select2/utils", "select2/data/select", "select2/data/minimumInputLength", "select2/data/maximumInputLength"], function (Utils, Select, MinimumInputLength, MaximumInputLength) {
            //changed the matches function to async
            Select.prototype.matches = async function (params, data) {
                var matcher = this.options.get('matcher');
                return await matcher(params, data); //added await which will call our defined matcher function asynchronously
            };
            //changed query function to async
            Select.prototype.query = async function (params, callback) {
                var data = [];
                var self = this;

                var $options = this.$element.children();


                for (var i in $options) {
                    if (!$options[i].tagName || ($options[i].tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'option' && $options[i].tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'optgroup')) {
                        break;
                    }

                    var $option = $($options[i]);
                    var option = self.item($option);
                    var matches = await self.matches(params, option); //added await to call the asynced matcher function
                    if (matches !== null) {
                        data.push(matches);
                    }
                }
                callback({
                    results: data
                });
            };

            var customSelectAdapter = Utils.Decorate(Select, MinimumInputLength);
            customSelectAdapter = Utils.Decorate(customSelectAdapter, MaximumInputLength);
            return customSelectAdapter;
        });
```

After creating the custom adapter by using the above code, I assigned the adapter to `dataAdapter` property (according to the [official documentation](https://select2.org/advanced/default-adapters/data)).

```
$(id).select2({
            placeholder: placeholder,
            allowClear: isClearAllowed,
            minimumResultsForSearch: minSearchResults,
            minimumInputLength: minimumInputLength,
            maximumInputLength: maximumInputLength,
            dataAdapter: $.fn.select2.amd.require("CustomSelectAdapter"), //assinged the custom created adapter
            matcher: async function (params, data) {
                .....
            }
        });
```